# Difference between symbolic links and shortcuts

Tags: java, symlink, shortcut, java.nio.file

What is the difference between symbolic links and shortcuts?

As I was reading Oracle's Documentation on **java.nio.file** package, there I came to know about **symbolic links**. At first, I thought they are talking about **shortcuts** because at first they both appeared the same to me. But later I realised that I am kind of assuming this without a proof so i googled it and found some links about the differences between the two. But I couldn't get a clear view of what these actually are as the answers were not that good. I hope I can get an explanation here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **symbolic link** is a special file which references another path on disk.  If an application opens this file (or includes it in a path), the operating system will silently follow the link.

For instance, assume you have a symbolic link `l` which points to a directory `d` with a file `file` in it. Observe:

```
$ ls d/
file
$ ls l/
file
$ touch l/file2  # Create a new file in the path under l
$ ls d/
file  file2
```

Symbolic links (symlinks) are a feature of the *filesystem* part of the operating system. They can be used by any application; applications that do want to treat symlinks differently (such as backup programs, which must not blindly follow symlinks lest the number of files becomes infinite) need to take special precaution to do so.

In contrast, a **shortcut** is a regular file which is rendered differently by the *user interface*(UI). A shortcut file also contains the desired target path, but can contain additional information, such as an icon, command-line arguments, instructions to the UI to run the destination as another user, categorization of the destination, translation information and the like. For an application, a shortcut is a regular file whose contents describe the shortcut. For instance, if you open a .desktop file with an editor, you'll see information like

```
Icon=libreoffice-calc
Exec=libreoffice --calc %U
GenericName=Spreadsheet
GenericName[da]=Regneark
```

You should generally use shortcuts if you want to add an entry to the user interface (typically the graphical parts). Shortcuts allow you extended customization - for instance, Danish users will see *Regneark*, and English users *Spreadsheet* in the above example.

If, on the other hand, you want the alias to be visible to all applications, go for a symlink instead. For instance, you could have a legacy name of a file that some applications expect, or one application that can do multiple things, or the current version of a project directory.

Note that some systems do not support symlinks, and some have no use for shortcuts. If there is no graphical interface present (for instance a home router without a monitor attached), shortcuts would not be useful. On the other hand, symlinks require support by the filesystem ([FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) has none) as well as the operating system (DOS/old versions of Windows lack support).